# AttributeError with __getitem__

Tags: python, class, attributeerror

I am making a `class` but when I test it I get very weird error messages,

This is my code:

```
class Kaart:  

    def __init__(self, rows = 10, colls = 10):
        self.rows = rows
        self.colls = colls
        self.matrixRC = []
        for _ in range(rows):
            self.matrixRC.append([2 for _ in range(colls)])    

    def __str__(self):
        retVal = '\n'.join(''.join(map(str, row)) for row in self.matrixRC)
        for index, new in enumerate((' ', '#', '?')):
            retVal = retVal.replace(str(index), new)
        return retVal

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        r, c = key
        return self.matrixRC[r][c]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        r, c = key
        self.matrixRC[r][c] = value

    def __iter__(self):
        self.matrixRC.__iter__()
```

And my test code is here:

```
import math
import kaart
map = kaart.Kaart()
print(map[1, 2])
```

but I get the error message `AttributeError: Kaart instance has no attribute '__getitem__'`

What am I doing wrong? I do have a `__getitem__` function so why doesn't he recognize it?

I am having the same problems with `__setitem__` and `__iter__` but not with `__str__`

Comment: Is the code you've pasted exactly what you're trying ? Even the indentation ?

Comment: It's not a good idea to use `map` as a variable name: that shadows the built-in `map` function, and when you try to call `map` in your `__str__` method, weird things will happen.

Comment: @PM2Ring Good point, it was just some test code but i'll keep that in mind (even with an other name I got the same result)

Comment: @Unatiel no, the indentation was different, in my program there is one tab of indent before every `def` and two or more before all other code

Comment: I can fix the indentation here, but it's still a bit mysterious why you're getting that error, and it _could_ be related to indentation. Are you using actual tabs, or does your editor convert tab key presses to 4 spaces? FWIW, it's safer to use spaces, unless you completely understand how tabs work in Python. But if you _do_ want to use actual tabs (rather than the tab key inserting spaces) you should tell your editor to make them visible so that you don't accidentally make a mistake.

Comment: BTW, there's a better way to do that string translation. Check this out: `table = str.maketrans('012', ' #?'); s = '012211012'; print(s.translate(table))`

Comment: @PM2Ring I am using BBEddit and tabs are tabs, i will look if i can make him display tabs more prominently and see if i can find a mistake

Comment: @BrendanMesters DONT use tabs, always spaces (4 of them).

Answer (score 0):

I think that your bug is a syntactic one, meaning that you do not indent all those functions that you are defining. They are not belonging to the class, but to the module's namespace. Try adding indentation for all of them and please let me know if that was the problem.

Comment: the functions are all indented, it just didn't come register on stack overflow, tough on my program there is one tab in front of all `def` and two or more in front of all other text

Comment: Try copy pasting the freshly modified code from your question, save it to a file, then rerun your testing code. I did just that and it works on my machine. It won't point the problem out, but at least it will shrink the bug space.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in indentation, i used tabs and quad spaces together, this caused problems which made it so that python couldn't identify the code.

Comment: That _is_ weird. Python 3 should throw an error if you mix tabs and spaces. OTOH, if you're using Python 2, then there are a few things you ought to change in your code. But it'd be better to migrate to Python 3.

Comment: I should be running python 3 tough... well, now it works and i have eliminated all tabs